# aggregation on datetime column resulting in errors

Tags: python, pandas

I am running into some very basic issues with aggregation. here is my code

```
    import pandas

    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {
            "person": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
            "d": [
                "2018-07-25 11:14:00",
                "2018-06-25 11:14:00",
                "2019-07-25 11:14:00",
                "2019-06-25 11:14:00",
            ],
        }
    )

    dataframe["date"] = pandas.to_datetime(dataframe["d"])
    print(dataframe.groupby("person").agg({"date", "min"}))
```

i got error `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date'`

and I can use `dataframe.groupby("person").agg({"date", ["min", "max"]})`, i got error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Thanks

Comment: `dataframe.groupby("person").agg({"date": "min"})` ?

Comment: yes. sorry. my bad. Thanks for spotting my error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was caused by a typo.

Comment: agree. sorry again